# Creating an animation after original animation without annoying clipping

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

In short, my problem is thus:

I am making an animation on a button when separate icons are animated on the hover on the trigger button, similar to this; `.button_class:hover ~ .seperate_class{}` and am wondering how to have an animation run after the element is no longer in `:hover` status. In my code, the icons rotate outward, grow and move slightly, and I want to animate them to return to the position before, essentially "undo" the animation.

*Just using the plain `:hover` works smoothly, but clips to the end destination*

```js
/*$(document).ready(function() {
 var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
 
 var firstScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: '#para_cont_1'
 })
 .setClassToggle('#para_cont_1', 'fade-in')
 .addTo(controller);
}); */

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn_link_2').mouseenter(function(){
       $('.wave1').addClass( "animationone" );
     $('.wave1').animate({opacity: '0.8',}, 1000);
    $('.wave2').addClass( "animationtwo" );
      $('.wave2').animate({opacity: '0.8',}, 1000);
    $('.wave3').addClass( "animationthree" );
     $('.wave3').animate({opacity: '0.8',}, 1000);
    });
   $('.btn_link_2').mouseleave(function(){
      $('.wave1').removeClass( "animationone" );
       $('.wave1').animate({opacity: '0',}, 1000); 
      $('.wave2').removeClass( "animationtwo" );
       $('.wave2').animate({opacity: '0',}, 1000);
      $('.wave3').removeClass( "animationthree" );
       $('.wave3').animate({opacity: '0',}, 1000);
   });
   //Coding for Shopping Store Button
   /*$('.btn_link_4').mouseenter(function(){
       $('.shirt').addClass( "grow_move_1" );
     $('.shirt').animate({opacity: '1',}, 1000);
    $('.pants').addClass( "grow_move_2" );
      $('.pants').animate({opacity: '1',}, 1000);
    $('.tie').addClass( "grow_move_3" );
     $('.tie').animate({opacity: '1',}, 1000);
    $('.dress').addClass( "grow_move_4" );
     $('.dress').animate({opacity: '1',}, 1000);
    $('.shoe').addClass( "grow_move_5" );
     $('.shoe').animate({opacity: '1',}, 1000);
    });
   $('.btn_link_4').mouseleave(function(){
       $('.shirt').addClass( "shrink_move_1" );
     $('.shirt').removeClass( "grow_move_1" );
      $('.shirt').animate({opacity: '0',}, 1000);
    $('.pants').addClass( "shrink_move_2" );
     $('.pants').removeClass( "grow_move_2" );
      $('.pants').animate({opacity: '0',}, 1000);
    $('.tie').addClass( "shrink_move_3" );
     $('.tie').removeClass( "grow_move_3" );
      $('.tie').animate({opacity: '0',}, 1000);
    $('.dress').addClass( "shrink_move_4" );
     $('.dress').removeClass( "grow_move_4" ); 
      $('.dress').animate({opacity: '0',}, 1000);
    $('.shoe').addClass( "shrink_move_5" );
     $('.shoe').removeClass( "grow_move_5" );
      $('.shoe').animate({opacity: '0',}, 1000);
    });*/
  });
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #d3bb9b;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 color: #2f3033;
}
.main_hd_cont {
 max-width: 100vw;
 width: 100vw;
 max-height: 7vw;
 height: 7vw;
 background-color: #9fc8eb;
 position: absolute;
 top: 6vw;
 left: 0;
 border-top: .5vw solid #183a12;
 border-bottom: .5vw solid #183a12;
 z-index: 2;
}
.contact {
 background-color: #d3bb9b;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 6vw;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.home_img {
 max-width: 13vw;
 width: 13vw;
 max-height: 13vw;
 height: 13vw;
 position: absolute;
 left: 45vw;
 top: -3vw;
 z-index: 3;
}
.home_img_2 {
 max-width: 100vw;
 width: 100vw;
 max-height: 50vw;
 height: 50vw;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 filter: blur(.2vw);
 background-image: url("../Images/HomeImg.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100vw 50vw;
}
.paratxt {
 position: absolute;
 top: 25vw;
 max-width: 100vw;
 width: 100vw;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2vw;
 font-family: 'Alegreya SC'Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
 color: #f1f1f1;
 text-shadow: 0 .2vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
.btn_link_1, .btn_link_2, .btn_link_3, .btn_link_4{
 max-width: 15vw;
 width: 15vw;
 max-height: 3vw;
 height: 3vw;
 border: none;
 background-color: #86acd7;
 position: absolute;
 color: #2f3033;
 border-radius: 4vw;
 font-size: 1.25vw;
 font-style: italic;
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
 transition: .5s;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-shadow: .5vw .5vw .5vw rgba(0 ,0 ,0, .5);
 font-weight: bold;
}
.btn_link_1:before {
 content: '';
 background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #fff, transparent);
 position: absolute;
 left: -15vw;
 top: 0;
 max-width: 15vw;
 width: 15vw;
 max-height: 3vw;
 height: 3vw;
 transition: .5s;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 4vw;
}
.btn_link_2, .btn_link_3, .btn_link_4 {
 top: 30vw;
 left: 8vw;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 3;
 transition: 2s;
 color: #2f3033;
 max-width: 17vw; 
 width: 17vw;
}
.btn_link_4 {max-width: 18vw; width: 18vw;}
.in_front {
 position: absolute;
 top: .7vw;
 left: 2vw;
 z-index: 5;
}
.tile1, .tile2, .tile3 {
 max-width: 33.5vw;
 width: 33.5vw;
 max-height: 32vw;
 height: 32vw;
 position: absolute;
 top: 66.5vw;
 left: 0vw;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Alegreya SC', Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 3;
 font-size: 1.5vw;
}
.tile2 { left: 33.5vw;}
.tile3 { left: 66.6vw;}
.sub_tile_hd_txt, .sub_tile_hd_txt_2 {
 font-size: 1.5vw;
 max-width: 21vw;
 width: 21vw;
 position: absolute;
 left: 6.5vw;
 color: #f1f1f1;
 text-shadow: .5vw .5vw .5vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
 transition: 1s;
 font-family: 'Alegreya', Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
}
.hd_txt, .snd_hd_txt {
 font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
 color: white;
 font-size: 2.5vw;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: absolute;
 top: -.5vw;
 left: 32.5vw;
 text-shadow: .25vw .25vw .25vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
 transition: .5s;
}
.snd_hd_txt {
 left: 60.5vw;
}
.hd_txt:hover {
 text-shadow: .15vw .15vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
.hd_txt:hover + .snd_hd_txt{
 text-shadow: .15vw .15vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
.sep_line_1, .sep_line_2 {
 max-width: .5vw;
 width: .5vw;
 max-height: 34vw;
 height: 34vw;
 background-color: #86acd7;
 position: absolute;
 top: 66.5vw;
 left: 33vw;
 z-index: 3;
 transition: .5s;
}
.sep_line_2 {left: 66.5vw;}
.tile1:hover + .sep_line_1 {
 max-height: 37vw;
 height: 37vw;
 top: 65vw;
}
.tile2:hover + .sep_line_2 {
 max-height: 37vw;
 height: 37vw;
 top: 65vw;
}
#para_cont_1, #para_cont_2, #para_cont_3 {
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 33vw;
 background-position: center;
 position: absolute;
 max-width: 33.5vw;
 width: 33.3vw;
 max-height: 35vw;
 height: 35vw;
 transition: 2s;
 filter: blur(.2vw);
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-bottom: 2vw;
 z-index: 2;
}
.circle {
 max-width: 14vw;
 width: 14vw;
 max-height: 14vw;
 height: 14vw;
 position: absolute;
 top: -4vw;
 left: 44vw;
 background-color: #9fc8eb;
 border-radius: 10vw;
 z-index: 1;
 border: .5vw solid #183a12;
}
.main_nav {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2vw;
 left: 5vw;
}
.main_nav a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #e8e8e8;
 padding-right: 1vw;
 font-size: 1.75vw;
 font-family: 'Alegreya SC', serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-shadow: .15vw .15vw .15vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
 transition: .5s;
}
.main_nav_2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2vw;
 right: 5vw;
}
.norm_txt {
 font-family: 'Alegreya', Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.25vw;
 padding-left: 1vw;
}
.fab {
 font-size: 2.5vw;
 padding-right: 1.75vw;
 opacity: .7;
 transition: 1s;
}
.sub_hd_txt_1 {
 max-width: 100vw;
 width: 100vw;
 max-height: 6vw;
 height: 6vw;
 position: absolute;
 top: 58vw;
 left: 0;
 font-family: 'Alegreya SC', Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
 color: #f1f1f1;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 5.5vw;
 font-size: 1.75vw;
 text-shadow: .25vw .25vw .25vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
 background-color: #9fc8eb;
}
.wave1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: .45vw;
 left: -5vw;
 width: 30vw;
 border-radius: 14.6675vw;
 background-color: #593C1F;
 height: 34vw;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 2;
}
.wave2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: .5vw;
 left: -3vw;
 width: 30vw;
 border-radius: 14.6675vw;
 background-color: #593C1F;
 height: 34vw;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 2;
}

.wave3 {
 position: absolute;
 top: .7vw;
 left: -9vw;
 width: 30vw;
 border-radius: 14.6675vw;
 background-color: #593C1F;
 height: 33vw;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 2;
} 
/* Icons8 Logos, grow, shrink, basic format, & animations start here (Shop Btn) */
.shirt, .pants, .dress, .shoe, .tie {
 filter: invert(1); 
 width: 1.5vw; 
 position: absolute; 
 z-index: 4;
 top: 30.5vw;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .5s;
}
.btn_link_4:hover ~ .shirt {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transition: 1s;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 6vw;
 top: 28vw;
 max-width: 2.5vw;
 width: 2.5vw;
}
.btn_link_4:hover ~ .shirt:after {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 transition: 1s;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 6vw;
 top: 28vw;
 max-width: 2.5vw;
 width: 2.5vw;
}
.shirt {left: 9vw;}
.pants {left: 12vw;}
.dress {left: 15vw;}
.shoe {left: 18vw;}
.tie {left: 21vw;}

.grow_move_1 {animation: grow1 .5s linear 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.grow_move_2 {animation: grow2 .5s linear 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.grow_move_3 {animation: grow3 .5s linear 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.grow_move_4 {animation: grow4 .5s linear 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.grow_move_5 {animation: grow5 .5s linear 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}

.shrink_move_1 {animation: shrink1 .5s linear 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.shrink_move_2 {animation: shrink2 .5s linear 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.shrink_move_3 {animation: shrink3 .5s linear 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.shrink_move_4 {animation: shrink4 .5s linear 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.shrink_move_5 {animation: shrink5 .5s linear 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}

/* Animation, Grow and move outward from btn: Shop Btn */
@keyframes grow1 {100% {max-width: 2.5vw; width: 2.5vw; top: 28vw; left: 6vw; transform: rotate(-45deg);}}
@keyframes grow2 {100% {max-width: 2.5vw; width: 2.5vw; top: 28vw; left: 26vw; transform: rotate(45deg);}}
@keyframes grow3 {100% {max-width: 2.5vw; width: 2.5vw; top: 33vw; left: 6vw; transform: rotate(-45deg);}}
@keyframes grow4 {100% {max-width: 2.5vw; width: 2.5vw; top: 33vw; left: 25vw; transform: rotate(135deg);}}
@keyframes grow5 {100% {max-width: 2.5vw; width: 2.5vw; top: 26.5vw; left: 15vw;}}

/* Animation, Shrink & move behind btn: Shop Btn */
@keyframes shrink1 {0% {max-width: 2.5vw; width: 2.5vw; top: 28vw; left: 6vw; transform: rotate(-45deg);} 100% {max-width: 1.5vw; width: 1.5vw; top: 30.5vw; left: 8vw; transform: rotate(45deg);}}
@keyframes shrink2 {0% {max-width: 2.5vw; width: 2.5vw; top: 28vw; left: 26vw; transform: rotate(45deg);}  100% {max-width: 1.5vw; width: 1.5vw; top: 30.5vw; left: 12vw; transform: rotate(-45deg);}}
@keyframes shrink3 {0% {max-width: 2.5vw; width: 2.5vw; top: 33vw; left: 6vw; transform: rotate(-45deg);} 100% {max-width: 1.5vw; width: 1.5vw; top: 30.5vw; left: 15vw; transform: rotate(45deg);}}
@keyframes shrink4 {0% {max-width: 2.5vw; width: 2.5vw; top: 33vw; left: 25vw; transform: rotate(135deg);} 100% {max-width: 1.5vw; width: 1.5vw; top: 30.5vw; left: 18vw; transform: rotate(-135deg);}}
@keyframes shrink5 {0% {max-width: 2.5vw; width: 2.5vw; top: 26.5vw; left: 15vw;} 100% {max-width: 1.5vw; width: 1.5vw; top: 30.5vw; left: 21vw; opacity: 0;}}

/* Media Queries for mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 740px) {
 .home_img_2 {background-attachment: scroll; background-size: cover;}
 .wave1 {animation: wave1 5s linear infinite; opacity: .8;}
 .wave2 {animation: wave2 9s linear infinite; opacity: .8;}
 .wave3 {animation: wave3 6s linear infinite; opacity: .8;}
 .main_nav {font-size: 7vw; width: 50vw; top: 0vw;}
 .main_hd_cont {max-height: 12vw; height: 12vw;}
 .home_img {max-width: 18vw; width: 18vw; max-height: 18vw; height: 18vw;}
 .circle {max-width: 19.5vw; width: 19.5vw; max-height: 20vw; height: 20vw; align-items: center; display: flex;}
 .fas {font-size: 2vw;}
}

/* Condensed 1-2 Lines Code Snippets */
.animationone {animation: wave1 5s linear infinite;}
.animationtwo {animation: wave2 7s linear infinite;}
.animationthree {animation: wave3 6s linear infinite;}
@keyframes wave1 {100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}}
@keyframes wave2 {100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}}
@keyframes wave3 {100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}}
.btn_link_1:hover:before {left: 15vw; border-radius: 4vw;}
.btn_link_1:hover {box-shadow: .15vw .15vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);}
.btn_link_2:hover {cursor: pointer;}
.main_nav a:hover {text-shadow: .1vw .1vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);}
.fas {font-size: 1.5vw; color: #2f3033;}
.fa-phone, .fa-fax, .fa-envelope, .fa-map-marker-alt {position: absolute; top: 2vw;}
.fa-phone {left: 10vw;}
.fa-fax {left: 28vw;}
.fa-envelope {left: 62vw;}
.fa-map-marker-alt {left: 82vw;}
.fab:hover {opacity: 1;}
.fa-youtube {color: #ff0000;}
.fa-twitter {color: #38A1F3;}
.fa-facebook-f {color: #3b5998;}
.fa-coffee, .fa-music, .fa-tshirt {color: #fff; font-size: 2vw;}
#para_cont_1 {top: 65vw; left: 0;}
#para_cont_2 {top: 65vw; left: 33.3vw;}
#para_cont_3 {top: 65vw; left: 66.6vw;}
.btn_link_1 {top: 30vw; left: 44vw;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
 <title>Heron Hosting | Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/stylesheet.css"/>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+SC:400,500,700,800|Alegreya:400,700|Cinzel+Decorative:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous"/> 
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
      <link rel="icon" href="../Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="../JavaScript/main.js"></script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale= 1.0"/>
 </head>
<body>
 <section class="contact">
 <i class="fas fa-phone"><span class="norm_txt">+1 (678)-737-6307</span></i>
 <i class="fas fa-fax"><span class="norm_txt">+1 (555)-444-3333</span></i>
 <i class="fas fa-envelope"><span class="norm_txt">jordanndunton@gmail.com</span></i>
 <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"><span class="norm_txt">37 Snapper Ln SE</span></i>
  </section>
 <section class="main_hd_cont">
  <header class="main_hd">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="../Images/OfficialHomeLogo.png" alt="Company Logo" class="home_img"/></a>
    <div class="circle"></div>
     <a href="index.html"><h1 class="hd_txt">Heron</h1> <h1 class="snd_hd_txt">Hosting</h1></a>
   <nav class="main_nav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Themes</a>
     </nav>
   <nav class="main_nav_2">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
   </nav>
   </header>
  </section> 
 <section class="body_cont">
  <div class="home_img_2"> </div>
   <h1 class="paratxt">Shop Hundreds of High Quality Templates</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='#'" class="btn_link_1">Shop Now </button>
  <h1 class="sub_hd_txt_1"> Featured Themes </h1>
    </div>
  <div id="para_cont_1" class="big_tile_1"> 
  <img src="../Images/CoffeeShopImg.jpg" alt="Coffee Shop Tile"/>
   </div>  
   <div class="tile1">
     <i class="fas fa-coffee"></i>
      <h1 class="tile_1_txt">Starting a Coffee Shop?</h1>
    <h2 class="sub_tile_hd_txt">We've got several templates that are just what you are looking for your coffee shop start-up. With smooth UI, elegant fonts, and simple, yet effective color palates for any atmosphere you might have</h2>
     <button type="button" class="btn_link_2"><span class="in_front">Browse Coffee Themes</span><div class="wave1"></div><div class="wave2"></div><div class="wave3"></div></button>
    </div>
  <div class="sep_line_1"></div>
   <div class="tile2">
     <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
      <h1 class="tile_2_txt">Selling Instruments?</h1>
    <h2 class="sub_tile_hd_txt_2">With several site concepts, feel free to browse for the theme that best suits the goals of your store. Utilize different designs to captivate your buyers, and make secure payments with your customizable shop page.</h2>
     <button type="button" class="btn_link_3">Browse Music Themes</button>
    </div>
  <div class="sep_line_2"></div>
    <div class="tile3">
     <i class="fas fa-tshirt"></i>
      <h1 class="tile_2_txt">Selling Clothes, Need a Site?</h1>
    <h2 class="sub_tile_hd_txt_2">Shop several different themes to best support your fashion line or upcoming chain. With smooth layouts, many templates offer a slick and modern feel for shopping. Sell T-shirts and shorts, or sell High Quality Dress clothes with a website to match.</h2>
     <button type="button" class="btn_link_4">Browse Clothing Themes</button>
      <img src="../Images/pants.png" alt="P" class="pants"/>
      <img src="../Images/shirt.png" alt="S" class="shirt"/>
      <img src="../Images/bowtie.png" alt="T" class="tie"/>
      <img src="../Images/shoe.png" alt="S" class="shoe"/>
      <img src="../Images/dress.png" alt="D" class="dress"/>
    </div>
  <div id="para_cont_2" class="big_tile_2">
  <img src="../Images/MusicStoreImg.jpg" alt="Music Store Tile"/>
      </div> 
  <div id="para_cont_3" class="big_tile_3"> 
  <img src="../Images/ClothingStoreImg.jpg" alt="Shopping Store Tile"/>
   </div>
```

Anyone know how to achieve this without JS, I'd prefer CSS if possible?

*Please view snippet in full screen to get the animation to work better.*

Comment: mouseenter/mouseleave --> this seems a job for the CSS hover, I think you are overcomplicating an easy task

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: have a look to "CSS hover" and "CSS transition" and you will find better and easier way to handle what you want .... it's insane to do this with JS, it will give you pain

Comment: :) I didn't notice (sarcasm) I've tried finding a way to perform keyframe animations with `:hover` pusedo elements. Could you perhaps give a basic example of doing so?

Comment: don't use animation too. Use transition. Basically you change the properties on hover and you don't apply animation

Comment: I was unaware that the CSS `transition:` element could be used to alter position and opacity. I will experiment with this, I'll get back with you if I make it work. Thank for your help! (Knew you guys would be great help)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks! It works, for the most part, it doesn't do the return animation that I'd like to have. Would the `:after` psuedo element work?

Comment: now you can make a quesiton with what you have and we can help with what is missing ;) [or edit this one]

Comment: Thanks so much! @TemaniAfif, have to wait 90 minutes, but I made a new question to post. :)

Comment: you can edit this one to avoid waiting

Comment: Okay, there posted the edited question :)

Comment: add some code to show the issue so we can correct your code

Comment: Although it has been a while, I finally found my problem. It was that I was using `transform: all .5s;` and not `transition: all .5s;`.

Answer (score 0):

first, I thihk you have to chain your jQuery methods .

```js
$('.btn_link_2').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.wave1')
    .addClass( "animationone" )
    .animate({opacity: '0.8',}, 1000);
  $('.wave2')
    .addClass( "animationtwo" )
    .animate({opacity: '0.8',}, 1000);
  $('.wave3')
    .addClass( "animationthree" )
    .animate({opacity: '0.8',}, 1000);
});
```

next, there is may be async considerartions in use

Comment: The wave animation is not the problem, not including it in the snippet caused errors in the other one. The `shirt`, `pants` etc. are the ones with the error. Sorry for confusion in that respect.